# Previous View after dismissModalViewControllerAnimated of email function somehow defect

Tags: iphone, xcode

i am trying and trying.... but no result yet.

i have a view with a navigationcontroller and -bar. in addition there is a tableview.
if you click on a row, the iphone email function is getting startet by using the email example from apple (MailComposerViewController.h and .m). 
it opens and i am able to send or cancel the mail. after that the "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated" methode is dismissing the emailing view. everything looks right, i am in the previous view now, BUT:
when i want to use buttons from the navigationitem or if i want to add rows to the tableview, the app is crashing without any error message.
do i have to set something back or to "remove" something which is still there because of the mailing view?
it's really strange and i am searching now for hours....... :-(

thank you very much in advance!
hopefully someone has an idea.

EDIT:
ok, here i have the code now:

in a tableview which is included in a navcontroller i have following lines to open first a Subclass of UIViewController:

```
- (IBAction)Action:(id)sender
{


        DetailViewController *editViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TripDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
            // ...
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:editViewController animated:YES];
        editViewController.navigationItem.prompt = @"Details";
        [editViewController release];


}
```

in the DetailViewController following action is processed when the user clicks on the button:

```
- (IBAction)mailTrip:(id)sender {

    MailComposerViewController *mailComposer = [[MailComposerViewController alloc] init];

    [[[self view] window] addSubview:[mailComposer view]];

    [mailComposer showPicker:sender];

}
```

when i press the related button, the MailComposerViewController pushes up correctly. all functions of the MailComposerViewController are working correct.
**but** when i send or cancel the mail and the MailComposerViewController disappears, my previous view doesn't work anymore.
in the MailComposerViewController-Example from apple the MailComposerViewController just disappear and the previous view is working fine again....  :-(

Comment: -1 Please provide minimal code which demonstrates the problem you are describing.

Comment: yes, sorry for this bad description, but i hoped it's a known, obviously problem. i will try to upload a code. thank you

Comment: Does someone has an idea? i guess it's a simple problem, but i dont find the solution... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found the stupid simple problem.
the MailComposer-View was after dismissing it still over the previous view.

i did set the propert hidden after dismissing and now it works...

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[[self view] setHidden:YES];
```

but i am really not sure if this is the right way to do it...